# Exception deploying SCDF App with Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am running SCDF with Docker Compose in Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL. I can create and deploy streams using starter sources/sinks without issue but when trying to deploy a custom Spring Cloud Stream app the following happens and I am not sure how to resolve it:

```
dataflow:>app register --name order-source --type source --uri docker://*******/****:order-producer
Successfully registered application 'source:order-source'
dataflow:>stream create ordering-stream --definition "order-source | log"
Created new stream 'ordering-stream'
dataflow:>stream deploy ordering-stream

Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: SkipperException
SkipperException
org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: SkipperException
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.handleError(VndErrorResponseErrorHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:780)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:416)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.StreamTemplate.deploy(StreamTemplate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.shell.command.StreamCommands.deployStream(StreamCommands.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.invoke(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.execute(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:59)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.AbstractShell.executeCommand(AbstractShell.java:134)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.promptLoop(JLineShell.java:533)
    at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.run(JLineShell.java:179)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This skipper server exception includes this:

```
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/tmp/1627185411996/ordering-stream.order-source-v1"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I can include the verbose server output if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem by referencing the application's jar file locally with Uri = file:///root/scdf/order-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. The docker-compose.yml file also needs to be inside the same directory as the jar file (~/scdf in this case). I'm still unsure why the Docker Hub Uri reference fails since docker is working for SCDF, all of the other services within Docker Compose, and elsewhere.